# opencv split vs mixChannels

Tags: opencv, image-processing, mat, hsv

To separate hue channel from HSV image, [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/back_projection/back_projection.html#code) is the code using the `mixChannels` function:

```
/// Transform it to HSV
cvtColor( src, hsv, CV_BGR2HSV );

/// Use only the Hue value
hue.create( hsv.size(), hsv.depth() );
int ch[] = { 0, 0 };
mixChannels( &hsv, 1, &hue, 1, ch, 1 );
```

But I know `split` function can also do this:

```
vector<Mat> chs;
split(hsv, chs);
Mat hue = chs[0];
```

Is that OK? 
If these are the same, I think split method is more clean. Am I right?

Comment: You are pretty much right, `split()` is used to split all the channels of an multi-channel matrix into single channel matrices. On the other hand if you are interested in only one channel you can use `mixChannels()`. So you don't have to allocate memory for other channels as we do with `split()`.

Comment: Good answer! You can put it to answer part so that I can accept.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are pretty much right, `split()` is used to split all the channels of an multi-channel matrix into single channel matrices. On the other hand if you are interested in only one channel you can use `mixChannels()`. So you don't have to allocate memory for other channels as we do with `split()`.

Answer (score 5):

Keep things simple and use [`extractChannel`](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gacc6158574aa1f0281878c955bcf35642&gsc.tab=0), which wraps `mixChannels` for you.

```
cv::Mat hue;
int cn = 0; // hue
cv::extractChannel(hsv, hue, cn);
```